# How to do the full page search by CefSharp?

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

Recently I have use the **Find()** function to do the text search on web pages in a CefSharp browser, and implemented **IFindHandler OnFindResult()** to get the found text count:

```
public virtual void OnFindResult( CefRefPtr< CefBrowser > browser, int identifier, int count, const CefRect& selectionRect, int activeMatchOrdinal, bool finalUpdate );
```

However, I have noticed if the web page is too long, the Find() function and the **count** from OnFindResult() only work for the first two pages. This issue doesn't only happen with CefSharp, but also in Google Chrome. I have uploaded an example html, it is very long and about 5 MB:

https://www.hihisoft.com/ss.html

If you try to use find() to find a word like "sox", it only return me 34 founded. But the actual quantity of the word would be much more. I attached a screenshot, you can see the browser only found on the first and second pages, but all the red annotated words has not been highlighted and found.

[image]

Is there a way to do the full page search with CefSharp? Let it return the actual text/word count.

Comment: How does `Chrome` of the same version behave? It could be a bug in `CEF`. You should download the `Sample Application` from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html
Remember that `CefSharp` is just a wrapper.

Comment: Yes it is a bug of CEF. I have tried the latest Sample Application, the bug still exists. May I know where I can report the bug? I see the forum doesn't allow to report bugs.

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/overview